# Tracking/Storing a variable across views with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am coding a pretty simple app that allows users to make certain selections and receive a random quote based on their selections. I have a pretty good idea on how to actually produce the quote but am stuck on how to track user selections until they get to the final view/page.

Specifically, my question is, how do I go about storing the user's selections in a variable or an array in a way that I can use it both on the last page and update it from any page for the quote generation? I haven't been using Angular for that long but what I've tried so far is making a service that includes an array for storing variables and then using directives on the buttons to update the array but this seems messy in the end with so many selections and it doesn't actually work right now.

Any and all suggestions or resources on how to achieve what I want are greatly appreciated <3

Comment: Use $rootScope   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope.

Comment: The service is a better way to go in my opinion, with $rootScope you still need to have it as a dependency like you would a service but it can turn messy on large application. Here even a service with an empty object would be sufficient to allow to set and access property on it through the application but still keep a data "namespace" in place.

Comment: I'll suggest doing a question with the service you are trying to do and how you are trying to use it, it would be a lot easier to find help this way.

Comment: I ended up using value to store the variable. The suggestions on $rootScope and creating a service definitely steered me in the right direction and broadened my  overall knowledge, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Defined this in my app.js

```
myApp.value('selection', {
  first: "first choice here",
  second: "second choice here"
});
```

And this in the controllers, updating the 'selection' based on the current view/ctrl along with the obvious necessary dependency injection

```
selection.first = "updated choice";
```